# Интегральные изображения open cv

Tags: python, opencv

По данной теме очень мало информации в интернете, из полезного только документация, которая особо не помогает. По заданию, используя модуль open cv, я должен вычислить интегральное изображение, здесь проблем не возникло.

```
image=cv2.imread("dom.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
summ,sqsumm,titled= cv2.integral3(image)
```

Первая величина, насколько я понимаю, искомая. Но получается довольно громоздкий массив данных:

```
 [[      0        0        0 ...        0        0        0]
 [       0      253      506 ...   114947   115201   115455]
 [       0      506     1012 ...   229919   230427   230935]
 ...
 [       0    36688    71843 ... 18750712 18800547 18851034]
 [       0    36751    71953 ... 18818463 18868519 18919227]
 [       0    36812    72069 ... 18887007 18937284 18988214
```

]]

Исходя из этого **первый вопрос**:

Является ли это окончательным ответом к заданию "найдите интегральное изображение"? Или можно сделать какие-либо еще преобразования, чтобы сделать из него картинку и отобразить через *cv2.imshow*?

Далее по заданию требуется, используя свойства интегрального изображения, найти горизонтальные и вертикальные линии в исходном изображении. Из этого **второй вопрос**:

Каким свойством я должен воспользоваться, чтобы получить нужный результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

integral**3** использовать ни к чему, т.к. для получения суммы достаточно просто integral

Чтобы отрисовать такой массив, его можно отнормировать, умножив на коэффициент `MaxFormatValue / TheLastElement`, где `MaxFormatValue` соответствует максимальному значению для используемого формата - например, 1.0 для матрицы формата 32f, или 255 для байтовой. Последний элемент-  максимальное значение в интегральном изображении, будет, таким образом, белым.

Для выделения горизонтальных линий нужно найти в правом столбце большие ступеньки - для белых линий, или слишком малое изменение - для чёрных.
Аналогично с нижней строкой для вертикальных линий.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, только есть вопрос касательно "ступенек". 
Как обнаружить эту "ступень"  для черных и белых линий ? Правильно я понимаю, что ступень это возрастание или убывание значений на определенном промежутке?  То есть где белая линия это возрастание, а где черная наоборот.

Comment: Нижняя строка (или правый столбец сверху вниз)- не убывает никогда. Может только расти (или оставаться на прежнем уровне для полностью черной линии). Можно нарисовать график, чтобы было понятно. Для анализа можно взять производную и посмотреть ее максимумы и минимумы

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что производные нужно брать уже от нормированного интегрального изображения ?

Comment: от указанных строки и столбца интегрального изображения

Comment: Еще раз спасибо